# How would one go about defining an event in an interface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, interface

I want my ICanTarget interface to have an event such as "OnTarget" that fires with a gameObject argument, every time it acquires a target. This can be AI Targeting or PlayerTargeting, hence the interface.

I want my combat script to respond to the targeting event coming from whatever ICanTarget component it has. Any Ideas?

Comment: The question is you don't know how to define a event in interface?

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ICanTarget
{
    event System.Action<GameObject> OnTarget;
}
```